# Sort the SQL table by name using maximum of quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL selection which return the following:

```
  Name   Code  Qty
 Janet   10   6
 Janet   11   9
 Janet   09   8
 Jones   12   7
 Jones   11   8
 James   09   5
 James   10   4
```

I want this selection to get sorted based on the qty for all the three people : order the people by their maximum quantity, and then order by quantity.

The output should look like this:

```
 Janet   11   9
 Janet   09   8
 Janet   10   6
 Jones   11   8
 Jones   12   7
 James   09   5
 James   10   4
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried anything ???

Comment: I don't get this, how come Janet's order 8, 9, 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify more than one sorting condition:

```
SELECT * from names order by name, qty desc
```

Above query will sort by `name` and if names are equal then will sort by `qty`

If you want to select only higher qty for every user then use this query:

```
SELECT name, MAX(qty) FROM names GROUP BY name order by MAX(qty);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty new and this didn't strike me immediately. If it's not too much to ask, could you please tell me how to return only the rows with highest qtys? I meant Janet's highest, James' highest etc.

Comment: @Morpheus `SELECT name, MAX(qty) FROM names GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 3):

This is a subtle problem.  It looks like you want to sort the *names* by the maximum of *qty*.  This requires a join and aggregation to get the maximum `qty` for each `name`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select name, max(qty) as maxq
      from table t
      group by name
     ) tt
order by tt.maxq desc, tt.name, t.qty desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, Code, Qty
FROM names AS main JOIN 
(SELECT Name, MAX(Qty) AS max_qty
 FROM names
 GROUP BY Name) AS max_names USING (Name)
ORDER BY max_names.max_qty DESC, names.Qty DESC
```

The virtual table `max_names` contains the maximal `Qty` for each `Name`:

```
Janet 9
Jones 8
James 5
```

Then you join it to the original table and sort according to this `max_qty`.

If you want to sort according to the total quantity per name, just replace `MAX` with `SUM`:

```
SELECT Name, Code, Qty
FROM names AS main JOIN 
(SELECT Name, SUM(Qty) AS sum_qty
 FROM names
 GROUP BY Name) AS sum_names USING (Name)
ORDER BY sum_names.sum_qty DESC, names.Qty DESC
```

The `sum_names` table will contain:

```
Janet 23
Jones 15
James  9
```

Comment: Thanks. Your virtual table is what I wanted to do finally.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `names` ORDER BY name ASC, qty DESC
```

Comment: `ASC` is obsolete here